# Using a dictionary of variable names with eval()

Tags: python

I know eval() is very useful for things like this:

```
x = 3
y = 2
myformula = "x + y"
print eval(myformula)
>>> 5
```

But what if I don't want to hardcode variable names and values but instead used a dictionary?

```
mydict = {'x':3, 'y':2, 'z':5}
myformula = "x + y + z"
print eval(myformula)
>>> 10
or,
mydict = {'a':100, 'b':10, 'c':1}
myformula = "(a * b) - c"
print eval(myformula)
>>> 999
```

I looked up how to assign a variable to a variable but I couldn't apply those other answers to my problem. I still want to keep that notation for myformula string. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Paul
Chicago, IL

Comment: what's wrong with using `mydict['a']*mydict['b'] - mydict['c']`?

Comment: What exactly do you need this for?

Comment: I want to do this because I have a txt file where I have variable names and values. I extract those variable names and values and then apply whatever formula I want to using eval(). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the second and third arguments to `eval` are for (read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)):

```
>>> d = {'x':3, 'y':2, 'z':5}
>>> eval("x + y + z", d)
    10
```

Do note that `eval`uating arbitrary user input isn't safe (think `rm -Rf /`). Avoid it.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple as that. Thank you!!